# Derivative of $x^TA$ wrt x

Tags: matrix-calculus

Wikipedia says that given $f(x) = x^TA$:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = A^T$$

but I am having trouble understanding this result. I tried doing the following:

$$f(x+h) - f(x) = h^TA$$

I am now stuck at making the above expression into a linear mapping of $h$. I'm not sure how to relate this to $A^T$. If $A$ were a vector, it would be easy because I could just switch the transpose and have $h^Ta = a^Th$. Since $A$ is a matrix, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Does writing the function as $\,f=A^Tx\,$ help with your understanding?

Comment: isn't that the transpose of f?

Comment: There is no essential difference between $x^TA$ and $A^Tx$, they are just the same vector represented as a row or a column. Usually you choose either a column or a row representation and stick to it. But in this wikipedia page $f(x)=x^TA$ maps a column vector to a row vector, and hence the confusion. Apparently it is not very self-contained.

Comment: I'll also add that the transpose is a linear function so that it is its own derivative. That allows you to calculate this using the chain rule.